# where exists with inclusion and exclusion statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data table:

```
patient_id    disease
hashA         HIV-2
hashA         COPD-1
hashA         diabetes
hashB         diabetes
hashB         FSGS
.
.
.
```

I would like to extract all the rows for patients who have diabetes, but not COPD or HIV.

So far, I have:

```
select t.*
from patient_table t
   where exists (select 1
      from patient_table t2
      where t2.disease like '%diabetes%' and
            t2.disease not like '%HIV%' and 
            t2.disease not like '%COPD%' and
            t.patient_id = t2.patient_id
)
```

This however does not exclude all the rows for patients with COPD and HIV. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the diseases that you don't want in an separate not exists

The code woud exluce pationet that has either copd or hiv

Edit:
ia dded a code of you need both other deseases excludes

> ```
> CREATE TABLE patient_table
>     (`patient_id` varchar(5), `disease` varchar(8))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO patient_table
>     (`patient_id`, `disease`)
> VALUES
>     ('hashA', 'HIV-2'),
>     ('hashA', 'COPD-1'),
>     ('hashA', 'diabetes'),
>     ('hashB', 'diabetes'),
>     ('hashB', 'FSGS')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select t.*
> from patient_table t
>    where exists (select 1
>       from patient_table t2
>       where t2.disease like '%diabetes%'  and
>             t.patient_id = t2.patient_id
> )
> AND NOT EXISTS (select 1
>       from patient_table t2
>       where
>             (t2.disease  like '%HIV%' OR 
>             t2.disease  like '%COPD%') and
>             t.patient_id = t2.patient_id)
> ```
>
> ```
> patient_id | disease 
> :--------- | :-------
> hashB      | diabetes
> hashB      | FSGS
> ```

> ```
> select t.*
> from patient_table t
>    where exists (select 1
>       from patient_table t2
>       where t2.disease like '%diabetes%'  and
>             t.patient_id = t2.patient_id
> )
> AND (
>         select count(patient_id)
>         from patient_table 
>         where (disease  like '%HIV%' OR 
>             disease  like '%COPD%') AND patient_id = t.patient_id
> )<2
> ```
>
> ```
> patient_id | disease 
> :--------- | :-------
> hashB      | diabetes
> hashB      | FSGS
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d67446d3538019cbc000587e26f4caa)*

Answer (score 1):

If you are (hopefully) using MySql 8 you can use `window functions` with a `conditional sum`

```
with cte as (
    select *, Sum(case when disease like '%HIV%' or disease like '%COPD%' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by patient_id) v
    from t
)
select patient_id, disease
from cte
where v=0
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5deffc37a714b836348af644249b2d3e)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*
from patient_table t
   where exists (select 1
      from patient_table t2
      where t2.disease like '%diabetes%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, might be helpful:

```sql
SELECT patient_table.* 
FROM patient_table
LEFT JOIN patient_table AS not_allowed_1 
    ON not_allowed_1.patient_id = patient_table.patient_id AND not_allowed_1.disease like '%HIV%'
LEFT JOIN patient_table AS not_allowed_2 
    ON not_allowed_2.patient_id = patient_table.patient_id AND not_allowed_2.disease like '%COPD%'
WHERE patient_table.disease like '%diabetes%' 
    AND not_allowed_1.patient_id IS NULL 
    AND not_allowed_2.patient_id IS NULL
```

It will left join each row which `disease like '%diabetes%'` twice with same table on rows with `disease like '%COPD%'` and `disease like '%HIV%'` then filters row which left joined rows has a value.

`Joining` is what SQL deeply know how to handle and this is way too much faster than `EXISTS` operator.